# Why doesn't combineLatest execute?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, reactivex

I am trying to execute a block of code using combine latest. I have a translation library that returns an RXJS Observable

combineLatest, map, and tap are imported as individual functions.

```
combineLatest(this.translate.transform('localizationText'))  <-- returns observable string
.pipe(
   tap(str => console.log(str)),   <----this is not firing
   map(str => str)
 );
```

Answer (score 5):

You still need to subscribe to observable for it to emit values.
So, add `subscribe` to your `pipe`

```
combineLatest(this.translate.transform('localizationText'))
.pipe(
   tap(str => console.log(str)),
   map(str => str)
 ).subscribe(v => console.log(v));
```

You can look at example usage of [`pipe` in documentation.](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md#usage)

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to avoid subscribe. But that makes sense.

Comment: You can avoid `subscribe` - by using `observable | async` in your template